# Python: Retrieve number of circles found with HoughCircles

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, hough-transform, opencv3.0, particles

I have been looking to use HoughCirlces to count the number of circles that appear in a given image, the image is only black or white and the circles are quite circular as they are from a particle detector and alpha particles come up as circles. The following snippet of code is what I am using currently but once the circles have been detected I don't know how to find out how many were found. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As a side not if anybody has a good way of finding accurate parameter values for HoughCircles for a given type of image that would also be helpful,

```
image = cv2.imread(imPath)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`circles` is a list with one element per found circle. The documentation states [0]:

"circles – Output vector of found circles. Each vector is encoded as a 3-element floating-point vector  (x, y, radius) ."

So `len(circles)` gives you the number of circles.

[0] http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles

Comment: Thanks for the help, however when I try to use len(circles) I get an error saying TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() and I don't know why. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: probably no circle was found. make sure you set `minRadius` and `maxRadius` right. Maybe try the tutorial first (with their image) and see if everything works as expected and then try it on your own image. Python tutorial: http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

Answer (score 2):

This question came up on a Google search and didn't work for me (the `len(circles)` always displays 1).  So I used `len(circles[0,:])` instead.